# Gdb scripting for core dump analysis

Tags: c++, gdb, coredump

I have a core dump for c/c++ application. I am new to programming so this question may sound silly. Is there some how I can write scripts to use gdb to analyze the core dump?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just script whatever you want. For example:

```
gdb \
   -ex "set pagination 0" \
   -ex "thread apply all bt" \
   -batch ${EXECUTABLE_FILE} ${CORE_FILE}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use -x option as below

```
$ cat gdb.cmds
set confirm off
set height 0
cd /homes/syrajendra
file dump
core dump.core
set solib-search-path "/lib"
bt
printf "\n"
quit

$ gdb -x gdb.cmds
. . .
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Core was generated by `dump'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  0x000000080149f6ca in thr_kill () from /lib/libc.so.7
#0  0x000000080149f6ca in thr_kill () from /lib/libc.so.7
#1  0x0000000801574149 in abort () from /lib/libc.so.7
#2  0x0000000801556011 in __assert () from /lib/libc.so.7
#3  0x000000000040130a in fun2 (num=100) at ./dump.cpp:10
#4  0x0000000000401343 in fun1 (num=100) at ./dump.cpp:20
#5  0x000000000040137e in main () at ./dump.cpp:27
```